# Specify knitr chunk options from external R script

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I currently render Rmarkdown documents in an external .R file using `rmarkdown::render()`. This allows me to dynamically specify YAML params as well as allow me to take advantage of knitr caching options by calling render repeatedly as needed. What I can't seem to figure out is how to specify knitr chunk options, both global and specific, from within the same external R script. Any advice on how to do this would be very helpful! Thanks in advance.

I tried specifying knitr options using `render(params = myParamsList)`; however, this only works for YAML front matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use R variables in chunk options, so this would work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2022-12-31"
output: html_document
params: 
  default.fig.width: 5
  special.fig.width: 4
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.width = params$default.fig.width)
```

This one gets the default width from `params$default.fig.width`:
```{r}
plot(1)
```

This one gets the special width from `params$special.fig.width`:
```{r fig.width = params$special.fig.width}
plot(2)
```

This one ignores the parameters:
```{r fig.width = 3}
plot(3)
```
````

Use `rmarkdown::render("Untitled.Rmd", params = list(default.fig.width = 3))` to set the default plot width to a smaller width, but leave the special one alone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This allows setting chunk options locally.  Can it be done globally? I have tried the following two options to set  'echo' globally with render(), neither of which works:

*1*
---
# YAML code
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
echo = params$setup.echo 
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE
)
```

*2*
---
# YAML code
params: 
  echo: `r params$echo`  
# also echo:  "`r params$echo`"
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine globally too:  just remember that what you set in the setup chunk is the default for later chunks.  It won't override explicit settings there.

Comment: I've modified the answer to show all three kinds of setting for the figure width.